# Yii - Populating a dropdown list

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, dropdownbox

I want to get a list of `productTypes` from the database and output them to a dropdownlist which will then be used to ajax populate a second dropdown list.

Step 1: Controller gets `productTypes` from database
Step 2: Controller converts the `productTypes` object to a list
Step 3a: Output list to test in view
Step 3b: Populate a dropdown with the list view

Snippet of controller

```
public function init()
{

    $this->dynamicTypes();
    $this->render('calculator', array('types' => $this->_types));
}


public function dynamicTypes()
{
    $this->_types = CHtml::listData(ProductType::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'type');
}
```

View File Snippet

```
<?php
    // Step 3a (this works fine)
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($types);
    echo '</pre>';

    // Step 3b - Returns an error
    echo $form->dropDownList('productTypes',1, array($types));
?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

With step 3b, I have tried the following:

```
echo $form->dropDownList('productTypes',1, array($types));
Error Msg: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
```

According to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail, the dropDownList method takes the following arguments:

```
public static string dropDownList(string $name, string $select, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

where the first argument is a **string** indicating the name of the input field.

What have I done wrong and how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('productTypes',1, array($types));
```

seems to work, but when I look at the dropdown in the view, for some reason, there is a 0 in the dropdownlist. For some reason, it is putting the options into an optiongroup

```
<select name="productTypes" id="productTypes">
<optgroup label="0">
<option value="1">Scrap</option>
<option value="2">Coin</option>
<option value="3">Bar</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

SOLVED:
Removed `array($types)`, replaced with just `$types`

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('productTypes',1, $types);
```

Comment: You get a grouped dropdown because you use `array($types)` instead of just `$types`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the `$form` is an object of the `CActiveForm` class. This version of the `dropDownList` method takes an instance of `CModel` class.

See the method signature here [CActiveForm::dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#dropDownList-detail)

Use

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('productTypes',1, array($types));
```

instead of

```
echo $form->dropDownList('productTypes',1, array($types));
```